# How to retrieve domain name from a webview?

Tags: java, android

I want to be able to retrieve the domain name in a webview in which the user is able to enter in the URL. I want to post the domain name instead of the URL if this is possible. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `getTitle()` and `getUrl()` on the `WebView` to get the current title and URL, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly (getTitle). I was using URL.getHost() but that also returned prefix (ex. www) and suffix (ex. .com). Thanks again, can't believe I missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) for the WebView and override its [onLoadResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onLoadResource%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method. This will tell you whenever a new web page is being loaded in the WebView, so you can parse that to get the domain and do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: I do have a WebViewClient in order to get the actual URL (after its done loading and redirecting). What would be the best way to parse it in order to get the domain name?